# Map not working when trying to get by entity name

Tags: java, telosys

I am using Telosys tool to generate entity classes and it is doing wonders for me.
However I have a specific requirement to change some attributes of entities.

I have loaded all the attributes that need to be changed in a map and parsed it in my entity template. But when I am trying to iterate through the map using entity.name it fails saying there is no get method.
This is my map: sample_map.vm

```
#set( $map = {
 "AABUHA": "Name",
 "ABAKTX": "Code",
 "ABABDZ": "Date"
 }
```

I parsed it in my template like this:

```
#parse("include/sample_map.vm")
```

And this is how I am trying to fetch the value for the corresponding entity

```
$map["${entity.name}"]
```

I also tried:

```
($map.get($field.name))
```

The error I get is either

```
$!map.[: no attribute '['
```

Or `no method get()`

Surprisingly, this works fine when I pass the value as hardcoded string.

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Velocity the error “`: no attribute '['`” ( or "`no method 'get'`" ) occurs when the key doesn’t exist in the map.

So, I suppose that in your case you try to get an “entity.name” that is not defined in the map.

To check if a key is defined in a map you can use :  `$map.containsKey("xx")`

See example here : https://doc.telosys.org/templates/velocity-objects#map

You can also use :  `$map.getOrDefault(“key”, "default_value")`
to get a default value if the key doesn’t exist in the map

Comment: This worked. Thank you. The error says nothing about no value found so it was hard to determine. Also, it is case sensitive which is sad too. But this solution worked.

Comment: Yes, it's the behavior of Velocity engine, errors with map objects are not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Technically my first answer works, but if you need to add specific information about an entity a "map" in the templates is not the best option (this information should be in the model).

So, I suggest using a "**tag**" ( # + tag name) positioned at the entity level (or attribute level) in your model ( in “.entity” file ).

For example:

In “**.entity**” file (a tag '**OtherName**' with a tag value):

> **#OtherName("Empl")**
> Employee
> {
> id : int { @Id } ;
> firstName : string { **#MyTag("xyz")** } ;
> }

In “**.vm**” file:
Usage 1 :

```
#if ( $entity.hasTag('OtherName') )
 name : $entity.tagValue('OtherName')
#else
 name : $entity.name
#end
```

Usage 2 - the simplest (with default value if no tag in entity) :

```
name : $entity.tagValue('OtherName', $entity.name)
```

Note : Tags are available at entity level since Telosys 4.0.0

See **hasTag()** and **tagValue()** in :

- https://www.telosys.org/doc/v400/objects/entity.html
- https://www.telosys.org/doc/v400/objects/attribute.html